# Most used word: mutt or pooch?

Tags: word-request

There are many dogs breeds such as golden retriever, poodle, pug and many others.

I would like to know the most common word used to refer to some dog that has no defined breed. I tried a translation of a common term used in my native language and I've got: `mutt` and `pooch`.

What of them are actually used?

Comment: Did you look up [the definition of *pooch*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pooch)?  It doesn't mean what you want, I think.

Comment: What @stangdon said. *Mutt* and *pooch* are simply slang/childish terms for ***dog*** in general (the former usually disparaging, the latter often "affectionate"). The word for a dog that has no defined breed is ***mongrel***, which isn't at all "slangy" (there's also ***crossbreed***, a somewhat more technical term that some would consider superior to a mongrel).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - [but "mutt" *does* tend to mean a mongrel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutt).

Comment: A purebred dog can be called a **pooch**.

Comment: Is my question so broad or opnion based?

Comment: As a matter of curiosity on Pets.SE both appear with roughly equal frequency.

Comment: *just a mutt* and *only a mutt* have hits; *just a pooch* and *only a pooch* do not: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=just+a+mutt%2Cjust+a+pooch%2Conly+a+mutt%2Conly+a+pooch&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjust%20a%20mutt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conly%20a%20mutt%3B%2Cc0  so, if you're deciding between them, use **mutt**.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK at least, the [Kennel Club](http://www.thekennelclub.org.uk/), which registers pedigree dogs, uses the term [*Mutt*](http://www.thekennelclub.org.uk/getting-a-dog-or-puppy/are-you-ready-for-a-dog/key-considerations-when-choosing-a-dog/) when describing a dog of uncertain pedigree.

The term *Mongrel* is widely used but is often thought nowadays to be a derogatory term - inferior to a pedigree.

Note that there are also other descriptions:
A [*Crossbreed*](http://www.thekennelclub.org.uk/getting-a-dog-or-puppy/finding-the-right-dog/crossbreed-dogs/) is a dog that is bred from two known and defined pedigree parents.
A [*Designer Dog*](http://www.thekennelclub.org.uk/our-resources/media-centre/issue-statements/designer-dogs/) is one of the newly recognised interbreeds, such as the *Cockerpoo* or *Puggle*.

Depending upon your intended use, I suspect one of these other terms may be better suited than either *Mutt* or *Pooch*.

Comment: Your two links to pages on ***thekennelclub.org*** contain nothing to suggest they specifically reserve the term ***mutt*** for *a dog of uncertain pedigree*. Quite the opposite, in fact, since the strong implication of the page titled *Choosing the right dog: key considerations to find the best mutt for you* is that the readers are likely to select a specific pedigree breed after considering their various characteristics. Plus I just did a site-wide search for the word ***mutt***, which didn't turn up anything else to support your assertion. It's just a "slang, affectionate" usage to them.

Comment: True, the *mutt* page is aimed at getting people to buy - and thus pay the KC to register - one of the recognised (inter)breeds.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: In AmE, **mutt** is often used as a synonym for a dog of unknown pedigree or the offspring of such a dog, the "opposite" of a purebred dog, so to speak.

Comment: @TRomano: I don't deny that - it's primarily an AmE usage anyway. I'm just taking issue with the idea that this specific meaning is somehow "endorsed" by the *(**British**)* Kennel Club.

Comment: I'm not saying that the word is *endorsed* by the KC, just used by them.

Answer (score 2):

To quote a TRomano's comment:

> mutt is often used as a synonym for a dog of unknown pedigree or the offspring of such a dog, the "opposite" of a purebred dog, so to speak

Because of this meaning, "mutt" has a negative connotation. As such, it may be used to describe a dog for which the speaker has some kind of negative feelings. If a purebred dog bit your hand, for instance, you may yell "You mutt!".

"pooch" is simply an alternative word for "dog". It's not used very often nowadays but almost everyone would understand what you mean. The idiom "screwed the pooch" (meaning the subject made a mistake) is the most common usage.